# Should CSS transforms be applied to the picture element or the child img element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-transforms

For applying CSS transforms to an image element, such as a `translate` or `translate3d` for example, would it be best in terms of performance to:

1. Apply the transform to the parent `<picture>` element

```js
const imageEl = document.querySelector('#image');

setTimeout(() => (imageEl.style.transform = "translateX(200px)"), 1000);
```

```css
#image {
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<picture id="image">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354"/>
</picture>
```

or 2. Apply the transform to the child `<img>` element

```js
const imageEl = document.querySelector('#image');

setTimeout(() => (imageEl.style.transform = "translateX(200px)"), 1000);
```

```css
#image {
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<picture>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" id="image"/>
</picture>
```

From what I gather it seems `<picture>` is effectively just an inline element like a `<span>` and thus intuitively I don't expect there will be much if any performance difference between applying transforms to the `<picture>` element versus the child `<img>` element. My question in a nutshell is: Are there any performance implications I should consider when deciding whether to place potentially taxing CSS transforms onto `<picture>` elements or child `<img>` tags - and if so then which placement is better for performance?

Comment: I think the `picture` tag, as you said, is just like `span` element, and so, the `img` tag is inside of it, so i think it doesn't really matter which one do you transform, as both is  correct. Because if you transform `picture` tag, the inside tags are going to transform, i think you don't transform the `picture` tag when you have more things inside of it, as all of the content will transform, but when you have only one element inside of the `picture` tag, it doesn't matter what you transform, while when you have multiple things inside of `picture`, you transform only what you need to.

Comment: But, aside of everything, a really good question.

Comment: @JovanJovanovic You make a good point there, but assuming I only have one or more `<source>` elements (which don't render) and one `<img>` element within the `<picture>` then I could choose to transform either and the same effect would take place - but it does seem like the logical option would be to apply it to the `<img>` since I don't need to move the `<picture>` itself. I'm mostly wondering if there are any concrete performance based reasons to go with one or the other in this case.

Comment: Yes, good point, but look what i found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). But check this out, `The <picture> HTML element contains zero or more <source> elements and one <img> element to offer alternative versions of an image for different display/device scenarios.` So basically, the `<picture>` tag is so you can put media queries without css. Therefore, i don't think its needed if you wont have media queries, you can just simply put a signle `<img>` tag

Comment: If `<picture>` is really an inline element like `<span>`, then it won't be possible to transform `<picture>` natively, since transform doesn't apply to inline elements. So, you would have to change the display property of `<picture>` to `inline-block` or `block`.